# custom gallery with swipe

Tags: android

What is the best way to present a full screen picture gallery read from a directory.

I was thinking of using an ImageView for full screen bitmap display and then using viewPager for swipeing to the next image. 
Which would mean that I would need to have at least PICTURE,PICTURE+1 and PICTURE-1 always in memory.

is this proper way or is there a better one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allows you to do what you want and recycles the fragments for reuse after swiping through

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: I guess the viewpager was the way to go.  It works great.  But i used the statepager because it also recycles views

Answer (score 0):

**-- Update --**

As pointed out in the comment, the gallery is deprecated.

The gallery doc says to use a ViewPager or a horizontal scroll list : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

**-- Old answer --**

Is there a reason you wouldn't want to use the built-in gallery ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

As for managing memories and bitmap, the android put up a post on this :

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html